# Retrieve user information from Active Directory on login

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory

I build one page ASP.Net required to login with Active Directory. The login is successful. But how to retrieve current user information from AD such as Full Name and display in my mainpage.aspx (C#)

I have try this on my code

```
using System.DirectoryServices;
```

---

```
   using (DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://SUTRA"))
        {
            using (DirectorySearcher adSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de))
            {
                string username = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["AUTH_USER"];
                adSearch.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=someuser)";
                SearchResult adSearchResult = adSearch.FindOne();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Comment: @MUHD MAN Are you getting errors on using the code that you have posted? If so what error ?

Comment: @jaycyborg: No error. but the result or output not shown.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return User's FirstName and LastName from AD

```
  public string GetUserDetails(string UserID)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectorySearcher search = default(DirectorySearcher);
            DirectoryEntry entry = default(DirectoryEntry);
            SearchResult sr = default(SearchResult);
            System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection propertycol = default(System.DirectoryServices.PropertyCollection);
            entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DomainName.com");
            propertycol = entry.Properties;
            search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
            search.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + UserID + ")";                
            sr = search.FindOne();
            string fname = "";
            string lname = "";

            if ((sr != null))
            {
                if (sr.Properties.Count > 1)
                {
                    fname = Convert.ToString(sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["givenName"].Value);

                    lname = Convert.ToString(sr.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["sn"].Value);
                }
                return fname + "\n" + lname ;
            }

          return "User Id not found";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error:" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```